# Ubuntu - How to fix empty sudoers file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

It looks like I made a mistake in the sudoers file.
I am not able anymore to login as root with `sudo -i`, I always get:

```
>>> /etc/sudoers: Syntaxfehler near line 38 <<<
>>> /etc/sudoers: Syntaxfehler near line 39 <<<
sudo: Syntax-Fehler in /etc/sudoers bei der Zeile 38
sudo: Keine gültige sudoers-Quelle gefunden, Programmende
sudo: Regelwerks-Plugin konnte nicht initialisiert werden
```

So I tried to edit the sudoers file, but I get `Error on reading file, no permissions`.

So I entered recovery mode and voila, I can see the file content, but I cannot edit it.

How can I possibly fix this without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Boot live distro (I think Ubuntu installer can work as such) and edit from there? **Tip: get familiar with `visudo` tool to avoid basic syntax errors while modifying the `sudoers` file.**

Comment: Where can I find the smallest live cd ?

Comment: Can you still log in as normal root, preferably from a virtual console ("text screen", Ctrl-Alt-F2 etc.)? If you can't, give root a proper password to avoid this problem next time. [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) is great for booting from CD or USB stick or even the Network to do system repairs.

Comment: @Black some real small live cd's are puppylinux, or I was looking at finnix the other day, it's about 170MB but may be command line only. I think TinyCore is 10MB to 20MB. Also, I don't remember exactly what the `single` boot option does, but it might be useful next time to get you logged in

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by downloading the minimal ubuntu from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), then I had to go to another computer to "burn" this file bootable on my USB device. After booting ubuntu mini in recover mode I corrected the syntax errors in the sudoers file and rebooted the system. Now it works again.

Comment: While there may be faster ways, you have my up vote for sharing the solution that worked for you.